# Twitter4J - authentication url unexpectedly loads in internet app

Tags: android, webview, twitter4j

Ok Im using Twitter4J, and a few months ago this exact piece of code was loading the authentication screen inside my Dialog styled activity.

Can someone explain why this piece of code is now loading the url in an external app like Chrome/Internet. The WebView is correctly placed into the view but is not showing the URL....
this is pretty weird.

```
mReqToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Starting Webview to login to twitter");
                    WebView twitterSite = new WebView(TwitterShareManager.this);
                    twitterSite.loadUrl(mReqToken.getAuthenticationURL());


                    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(TwitterShareManager.this); 
                    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL); //added after suggestion
                    ll.addView(twitterSite);
                    setContentView(ll);                 

                }
            });
```